# Do I need more RAM to avoid repeating standstills in TF2?

Tags: nvidia, games, ram, steam

Ok I built my PC 2-3 days ago. Got Ubuntu 12.04 LTS up and running.

Got my nVidia GT220 card finally working and now when I play TF2 it plays fine but after about 15 mins of gameplay it pretty much came to a standstill on a loading screen.

My mouse started to lag and barely move after a while. This also happened on DOTA 2. I believe it's my RAM. I have a Mushkin 2GB DDR3 installed. When I look at the hardware, though, it shows it as 1.4GB.

Is lack of RAM problem? Also my other parts are a AMD A4 Llano APU, MSI a55m-p33 mobo, and the OS and games are on a Toshiba 500GB laptop HDD. Can anyone give any insight to this?

Comment: sound as a bad nvidia cofiguration, try with this tutorial http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-pangolin-nvidia.html

Comment: Increasing the RAM may help for your case. I Play TF2 in a 8GB RAM computer and I yet experience some lag from time to time. TF2 is not that much RAM demanding but when playing with no other processes running it may "eat" up to 4GB RAM, depending on the server, map, number of total players and game you're playing. Good luck!

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. As it stands, your question is too opinion-based, making it more a *discussion* rather than a *question with a definite answer*. Therefore, it's not suitable for this website. However, I highly recommend asking this at a place where discussions are welcome - [the Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/). Cheers!

Comment: @Mochan There is nothing opinion-based about this question that I can see.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 The question itself isn't opinion-based, but what it is asking will obviously result in opinion-based answers. The OP is asking for clarification, meaning he is seeking an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitor your RAM usage with the System Monitor program. If you run out of RAM during gameplay, you should consider purchasing an upgrade to solve the issue. I wouldn't recommend increasing the swappiness level as a permanent solution because it affects the whole system, but it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is your RAM. You can try lowering the swappiness level to 10 with `sudo sysctl vm.swappinnes=10`. Maybe this will help you a little bit... But I have to say that this happens to me too, but my laptop is intel-only, but the point is that on Windows those problems don't occur, making me think that maybe it's a porting problem.

BTW, swappiness is the process on which your system paginate or move program data to secondary memory (swap space on hard disk) to make space for other processes. The problem with this is that the procces causes a lot of overhead, mainly with heavy games.It did help me, so, maybe it will help you.

Comment: I have a s spare ps3 hdd plugged in the second sata port can I use that instead my main hdd.?

Comment: That's a new question to ask... putting new questions in comments likely won't get answered here.

Comment: kay. thx @kiloseven

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Mushkin 2GB DDR3 installed. When I look at the hardware, though, it shows it as 1.4GB.

The absent 0.6GB is typically used for graphics, hence the discrepancy.

Some PCs work better when memory is installed in matching pairs of DIMMs; heck, some servers want troikas of DDR3. Your motherboard has dual memory channels as per http://us.msi.com/product/mb/A55M-P33.html#/?div=Basic, so memory would run 10% faster if you instead had a pair of 1GB DDR3 DIMMs, and adding another 2GB DIMM from the same manufacturer with the same specs would speed things up more.